# Global variable in Jest test

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have a java script code where I need to test a result based on global variable. The code is ver big, so I would not post it here, instead of that I would like to post very simple sample.

future.js

```
let newHire = false;  //Global variable

const cert = () => {
  if (newHire) {
    console.log('newhire is true');
  } else {
    console.log('newhire is false');
  }
  return newHire;
};

module.exports = {
  cert,
};
```

future.test.js

```
const mapper = require('../../../libs/future');

describe('Test that certis working', () => {
    it('Test cert',  () => {
        mapper.newHire = true; 
        const result = mapper.cert();
        expect(result).toEqual(true);

    });
});
```

I got allways following error:

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Expected: true
Received: false
```

It is obvious that I am unable to change value of newHire inside the test.
How I can solve this issue?

Comment: You can't. The code is architectured in such a way as to not be testable. Global variables at the module level being mutated between calls is a huge code smell and also is making it hard to test. This code needs refactoring to be encapsulated in a class or similar. Or simply pass newHire as an argument.

Comment: It's not actually global variable, it's rather module-scope variable, and presumably you either have another method for changing it's value, which you can use in your test to change it's value, or your implementation has a path which would never be reached

Comment: yes correct, I have another function to change that variable @Teneff

Comment: Then you should use it in your test in order to modify `newHire`'s value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it as following:
future.js

```
let newHire = false;

const cert = () => {
  if (newHire) {
    console.log('newHire is true');
  } else {
    console.log('newHire is false');
  }
  return newHire;
};

const setNewHire = (value) => {
  newHire = value;
};

module.exports = {
  cert,
  setNewHire,
};
```

future.test.js

```
const mapper = require('../../../libs/futureData/future1');

describe('Test that cert is working', () => {
  it('Test cert', () => {
    mapper.setNewHire(true);
    const result = mapper.cert();
    expect(result).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).